# hostname manipulation in makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

In my makefile, I have the following condition using ifeq directive

```
HOST:=$(shell hostname)
ifeq ($(HOST),tier2-p-login-1-hpc)
        export CXX=h5c++
        export HDF5_CXX=mpic++
        export HDF5_CLINKER=mpic++
endif
```

I do make on an arbitrary node of the cluster, whose hostname is of the form `tier2-p-login-xxx-hpc` where `xxx` indicates a particular node (ex `tier2-p-login-17-hpc`). My question is how can I pattern match $(HOST) with the form `tier2-p-login-xxx-hpc` ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does **CMake** relate to the question? If not, why do you use "cmake" tag?

Comment: I thought the tag might be relevant for the cmake community but anyways I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ifneq (,$(filter tier2-p-login-%-hpc,$(HOST)))
  ...
```

which says "if the result of filtering `$(HOST)` against the pattern `tier2-p-login-%-hpc` is not empty ..." (e.g., the value matches the pattern)

Comment: In the same line of thought, I tried this `HOST2:=$(patsubst tier2-p-login-%-hpc,tier2-p-login-hpc,$(HOST))` and then `ifeq ($(HOST2),tier2-p-login-hpc)` such that I can replace tier2-p-login-%-hpc with tier2-p-login-hpc and call it HOST2 to be used later in the makefile.